# how can we insert an array with last_insert_id into a table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, split

I have a stored procedure in mysql with this syntax:

```
    insert into tbl1 (p1, p2) values (p2, p3);
    set inserted_id = last_insert_id();
    insert into tbl2 (id, image) values (inserted_id, 'list_of_image');
```

now i don't know how can i separate this image list(that doesn't have fixed count) for this insert.
any idea?

Comment: right, but in high number of image it has high overhead

Comment: what is the relation between tbl1 and tbl2? and how high is the number you are talking about?

Comment: how can i separate images from each other? i pass all of them together. images of a person inserts in tbl2 and his properties insert into tbl1

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `'list_of_image'` is a comma-delimited string of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `'list_of_image'` is a string that contains comma-delimited values you can do following with pure SQL

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_images(IN p3 VARCHAR(64), IN p4 VARCHAR(64), IN images VARCHAR(512))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Table1 (p1, p2)
  VALUES (p3, p4);

  INSERT INTO Table2 (id, image)
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(i.images, ',', n.n), ',', -1) image
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT images images
  ) i CROSS JOIN 
  (
     SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
     ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
      ORDER BY n
  ) n
   WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(i.images) - LENGTH(REPLACE(i.images, ',', '')));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call your SP

```sql
CALL sp_insert_images('Some value1', 'Some value2', 'image1, image2, image3');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37a19/4)** demo.

**Note:**

1. The example query will split up to 100 comma-separated values. If you need more or less you can adjust a limit by editing the inner subquery.
2. You might consider to create a permanent tally (numbers) table and use it instead of inner select (with an alias `n`) that produces a sequence of numbers on the fly.